# Blurred Circle detection

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am new to opencv and want to detect the center point of these circles. I tried with Hough Circles with thresholding but it doesn't seem to generate good results all the time.

This image is easy to get using contours and threshloding:

[image: This image is easy to get using contours and threshloding]

It is harder to do this one:

[image: It is harder to do this one]

The thresholding and Hough circle doesn't work with this image:

[image: The thresholding and Hough circle doesn't work with this image]

[Adding more images for help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ACej.png)

Can you suggest any method that will be reliable for all the images?

Comment: It would be better if you could embed the images, as link rot will mean this post becomes less useful in the future. Also you may find more help on Cross Validated for this kind of question.

Comment: To work correctly with houghcircle you need to determine its parameters correctly. I also dont like to use houghcircle, I shared in [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lTbOKh_wJF0) the algorithm I use to detect circles.

Answer (score 6):

Since the circle is the only bright thing in the image, we can get the center by looking for the centroid of the white blob. We'll auto-threshold with otsu's and use findContours to get the centroid of the mask.

[image]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("circ1.png");
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

# threshold
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0);
_, mask = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU);

# contour
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

# center
M = cv2.moments(contours[0]);
cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00']);
cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00']);
center = (int(cx), int(cy));

# draw
img = cv2.circle(img, center, 4, (0,0,200), -1);

# show
cv2.imshow("marked", img);
cv2.imshow("mask", mask);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```